# Model of a shared service isn't updating in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), I have two controllers that share the same service in my application.
When I fire an event that's controlled by the `portalController` function (see `setLang()`), I don't see the model of applicationController being updated.

This problem seems to appear only with Firefox and Chrome. In IE8 it is unexpectedly working fine.

#### PortalController

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllers = angular.module('portal.controllers');

controllers.controller('portalController', function portalController($scope, UserService, NavigationService, $translate) {
    $scope.User = UserService.getUserinfo();

    $scope.setLang = function (langKey) {
        $translate.uses(langKey);
        UserService.setUserinfoLocale(langKey);
        UserService.getUserApplications(Constants.key_ESS);
        UserService.getUserApplications(Constants.key_MED);
        UserService.getUserApplications(Constants.key_SVF);
        $.removeCookie(Constants.cookie_locale);
        var domain = document.domain;
        if (domain.indexOf(Constants.context_acc) != -1 || domain.indexOf(Constants.context_prd) != -1 || domain.indexOf(Constants.context_tst) != -1) {
            domain = "." + domain;
            $.cookie(Constants.cookie_locale, langKey, {path:"/", domain:domain});
        } else {
            $.cookie(Constants.cookie_locale, langKey, {path:"/"});
        }
    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
        NavigationService.logout();
    };


    $translate.uses(UserService.getUserinfoLocale());


});
//mainController.$inject = ['$scope','UserInfo'];


}());
```

#### ApplicationController

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var controllers = angular.module('portal.controllers');

controllers.controller('applicationController', function ($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.ESS = UserService.getUserApplications(Constants.key_ESS);
    $scope.SVF = UserService.getUserApplications(Constants.key_SVF);
    $scope.MED = UserService.getUserApplications(Constants.key_MED);
});
}());
```

#### The shared UserService

```
UserService.prototype.getUserApplications = function(entity){
    var locale = this.getUserinfoLocale();
        return this.userApplications.query({locale: locale, entity: entity});
};
```

#### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/GFVYC/1/

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: here's the link to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GFVYC/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using $scope instead of $rootScope,
the data gets updated through the first controller in the service but there's nothing that informs the second controller of this change:

#### code in the first controller that notifies $rootScope of a change

```
$scope.setLang = function(locale){
        $rootScope.data = sharedService.getData(locale);
};
```

#### code in the second controller watching for change

```
    $rootScope.$watch('data', function(newValue) {
        $scope.data = newValue;
    });
```

below is a link to the 'wrong' fiddle and one that works for when somebody else also has this problem:

wrong one: http://jsfiddle.net/GFVYC/1/
working one: http://jsfiddle.net/GFVYC/4/